# Limit socket connection in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have NodeJS server that users can connect to it with socket in Mobile App(Android and iOS)

No problem now

Only any user can connect to this server

If you know what is ip and port so can connect to it

How do i can prevent from connecting invalid user?

Comment: (1) Firewall rules, or (2) TLS client authentication, or (3) authentication in the application protocol.

Comment: @EJP i am new in NodeJS,do you can guide me simply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Omid Aghakhani what you can do is:

- Ask user for the valid credentials by asking username or email and password before which you want them to register on your app. Store their credentials in db. At the time of login ask them to enter the same
- Other is set a secret key in you file. Ask the key from the user who want to connect and validate.
- There are many other authentications provided like **PASSPORT**.You need to get a little bit more experience to use these.

Good Luck

Comment: It is good solution but i have a question,when i try connect to socket,i cannot send data together connecting,actually first i have to connect to socket and then send data for validate it,it it?

Comment: @menta-rohan Thanks my problem solved.I send data after connection socket contain key that in server must be match